# What is the title of this Macintosh programming book?

Tags: apple-macintosh, programming, software-development, books

Back when Mac OS was called "System" and preemptive multitasking was a distant fantasy, I had a small collection of Macintosh programming books.

For the life of me, though, I can't remember what one particular book was called, or who wrote it. I do remember, though, a few things about it:

- It wasn't terribly long, maybe ~200 pages.
- It had a brightly-colored cover; I think orange, but I could be wrong.
- It was written in a conversational style with a lot of that mid-90's cool-guy attitude.
- There was a section on graphics programming that started with a wisecrack about programmers getting inspired by Ambrosia's Maelstrom and getting lost in the complexities of dealing with GWorlds and sprites before giving up and going back to playing Maelstrom.
- There was a chapter on non-traditional programming environments, including a brief discussion of the Forth-derived "Mops" and "Yerk", which the younger me thought were hilarious.
- It included a CD with lots of the shareware/freeware tools discussed.

I would love to try and track down a copy, but I can't remember what it's called! Can you help me find it?

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing. I think this question might warrant a new tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could it be [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/Bytes-Mac-Programmers-Cookbook-Terrell/dp/0078820626)?

> *Byte's Mac Programmer's Cookbook Paperback – May 1994
>   by Rob Terrell (Author)*

I once had (and enjoyed) it when I still had a Macintosh. Just like the Mac, my issue has unfortunately long gone the path of all obsolete.

And, as an added service:

[Apple Rescue of Denver](http://www.applerescueofdenver.com/products-page/macintosh-books-manuals/byte-mac-programmers-cookbook/) still seems to sell new copies for a whopping $15.